# How to get only value for a value in a list without braces([' '])

Tags: python

```
mylist = [ {'name': 'Hello',
            'Network': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}],
            'place' : 'India'
           } , 
           {'name': 'Hiii',
            'Network': [{'key1': 'value1'}, {'key2': 'value2'}],
            'place' : 'Africa'}]
```

Here

```
print mylist[0]['Network'][0].values()
```

gives output as

```
['value1']
```

But I want only the value "value1" without braces sorrounded.

Comment: You got a list. Extract the first item and you'll have just your `'value1'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most direct answer to your question is:

```
>>> print mylist[0]['Network'][0].values()[0]
value1
```

You can also ask for the value by its key:

```
>>> print myList[0]['Network'][0]['key1']
value1
```

The reason you had *brackets* surrounding your result is because `dict.values()` returns a `list` of all the values, even if there's only one.

Answer (score 0):

Try print mylist[0]['Network'][0].values()[0] as value1 is just the first value in this list.